# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'insert' referenced before assignment on server side

Tags: python, django, django-views, variable-assignment, local-variables

I have built a keyword research application and it is running successfully on a local server but when I deployed it to `Cpanel` it is throwing me an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'insert' referenced before assignment:

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
def funcurlscrpping(url):
    
    urldata = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urldata.content, "html")
    title = soup.title.string
    print ('TITLE IS :', title)
    meta = soup.find_all('meta')
    for tag in meta:
        if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['keywords']:
            insert = tag.attrs['content']
            print(insert)
    data = insert.split(',')
    return data

def funcurlscrppingwithkeyword(ids):

    for id in ids:
        videourl= 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+ id 
        urldata = requests.get(videourl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urldata.content, "html")
        title = soup.title.string
        print ('TITLE IS :', title)
        meta = soup.find_all('meta')
        for tag in meta:
            if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['keywords']:
                insert1 = tag.attrs['content']
                print(insert1)
        data1 = insert1.split(',')
    return data1

def GetTags(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        url = request.GET['query']
        type = request.GET['type'] 
        valid=validators.url(url)
        if valid==True:
            obj1=[]
            obj1 = funcurlscrpping(url)
            if type == 'YouTube':
                return JsonResponse({"tags": obj1}, status=200)
            else:
                res = ['#' +  x  for x in obj1]
                return JsonResponse({"tags": res}, status=200)
        else: 
            search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
            params = {
            'part': 'snippet',
            'q':url,
            'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY,
            'maxResults' : 2,
            }
            video_ids = []

            r = requests.get(search_url,params = params)
            results = r.json()["items"]
            for result in results:
                video_ids.append(result['id']['videoId']) 
            obj = []
            obj = funcurlscrppingwithkeyword(video_ids)
            if type == 'YouTube':                     
                return JsonResponse({"tags": obj}, status=200)
            else:
                res = ['#' +  x  for x in obj]
                return JsonResponse({"tags": res}, status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Request method is not a GET")
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can come from here:

```
for tag in meta:
        if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['keywords']:
            insert = tag.attrs['content']
            print(insert)
    data = insert.split(',')
```

and here:

```
for tag in meta:
            if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['keywords']:
                insert1 = tag.attrs['content']
                print(insert1)
        data1 = insert1.split(',')
```

It can happen that insert is not being initialized if the condition is not true. You can fix this by initializing the `insert` before the for loop.

```
insert = ""  # some default value that works
for tag in meta:
        if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['keywords']:
            insert = tag.attrs['content']
            print(insert)
    data = insert.split(',')
```

and the other one:

```
insert = ""  # some default value that works
for tag in meta:
                if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['keywords']:
                    insert1 = tag.attrs['content']
                    print(insert1)
            data1 = insert1.split(',')
```

Comment: actually, I figured out the problem, by running a simple example on the server as, it seems that the beautiful library into python might not be working properly with the youtube scrapping, so I decided to use youtube API instead of scrapping. and yes it was throwing the null factor, @hendrikschneider, you were right.. Thanks, for the corporation.